# JQuery Only executing If an Alert() is placed before it

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Each time a user click the "Get Quote" button, a GIF animation is shown and the old display is hidden.

I query a backend service which returns some HTML that I just dump onto the page (I take advantage of SMARTY in the API to handle the formatting for me given my crappy front-end skills). When an error occurs, instead of HTML, JSON is returned (thus the kinda backwards try catch, in this instance the "success" is happening in the "catch" and the "failure" is happening in the "try").

When an error occurs, HandleMessages() gets the response, and deals with the messages that are stored there(This works fine).
After the errors are handled, the GIF should disappear (since it's in a .collapse and I'm hiding it). This is NOT happening and ONLY happens when I alert() something to the page. If the alert() is commented or missing, this doesn't work.

I'm sure it's something super stupid, or silly, but your help is always appreciate.

Here's the Code:

```
$('#findCarriers').click(function(){

    var data = new Object();

    $('#carrierLoad').collapse('show');
    $('#carriers').collapse('hide');

    data.general = {
        'code': $('#warehouse').val(),
        'shipper': $('#shipper_zip').val(),
        'consignee': $('#consignee_zip').val(),
        'shipment_type': $('#direction').val(),
        'total_weight': $('#total_weight').text(),
    };

    data.accessorials = [];

    $('#accessorials').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(acc_index){

        data.accessorials.push($(this).val());

    });

    data.units = [{
        'num_of': $('#total_pallets').val(),
        'type': 'pallet',
        'weight': 0
    }];

    data.products = [];

    $('#items tr').each(function(index){

        data.products.push({
            'pieces': 1,
            'weight': parseFloat($(this).find('.weight').val(), 10),
            'class': parseInt($(this).find('.class').val(), 10)
        }); 

    });

    $.post('index.php?p=api&r=html&c=ctsi&m=lcc', data, function(resp){
        try {

            resp = $.parseJSON(resp);
            handleMessages(resp);

            carriersClear('find carriers');
            alert('good'); // comment out or remove and the show and hide on the collapse never happens
            $('#carrierLoad').collapse('hide');
            $('#carriers').collapse('show');
        } catch(err) {

            $('#carriers').html(resp);
            alert('fail'); // comment out or remove and the show and hide on the collapse never happens
            $('#carrierLoad').collapse('hide');
            $('#carriers').collapse('show');

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

Helper functions:

```
function setError(e_title, e_msg, e_type) {

    $.pnotify({
        title: e_title,
        text: e_msg,
        type: e_type
    });

}

function handleMessages(jsResponse) {

    $.each(jsResponse.message, function(){

        setError(this.traceroute[0] + '-' + this.traceroute[1] + '-' + this.traceroute[2], this['message'], this['type'])

    });

}

function carriersClear(reason) {

    $('#carriers').html('');

    //alert(reason);

}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="span10">

    <h3 class="heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#carrierSelect">Carriers</h3>

    <div class="bg-light collapse in bg-light" id="carrierSelect">

        <div class="row spacer-top spacer-bottom">

            <div class="span2 offset8">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="findCarriers">Get Quote</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row spacer-bottom collapse" id="carrierLoad">
            <div class="span2 offset4"><img class="center-block" src="view/img/load.gif" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="span10 bg-x-light collapse in spacer-top" id="carriers">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If something works with an `alert()`, it's a sure sign that you have some async action going on, and that the delay the alert makes does all the difference.

Comment: Where's the code for `handleMessages()` and `carriersClear()`?

Comment: Can you elaborate. I'm basically useless with jQuery, so an explaination would be awesome, a suggested fix would be great too.

Comment: For the record, if there's an error, it comes back almost instantly.

This also works fine when there are **no** errors. I'm only having issues when there are errors that need handled.

Comment: @Juhana Helpers added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the lines after carriersClear() into the carriersClear function as a callback. Like so:

```
$.post('index.php?p=api&r=html&c=ctsi&m=lcc', data, function(resp){
    try {

        resp = $.parseJSON(resp);
        handleMessages(resp);

        carriersClear('find carriers', function(){
            $('#carrierLoad').collapse('hide');
            $('#carriers').collapse('show');
        }
    }
```

then:

```
function carriersClear(reason,callback) {
    $('#carriers').html('');
    callback();
}
```

Comment: After more tinkering I actually wired it all around bootstrap collapse events but you got me set on my way.